# Should we use a single execution stored procedure with table parameters or multiple execution procedure with separated parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, stored-procedures, processing-efficiency

I am working on a WinForms Desktop Application. On this application I have to make some updates on SQL Server database. I can do it this with a stored procedure with **table parameters**

```
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@changes", changes.ToTable(false, "ItemNo", "Info"));
```

and execute the procedure **just once**, or with a loop execute the procedure **multiple times** with string parameters.

```
for (...)
{
   ...
   comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", "Item 1"));`
   comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Info", "Info 1"));`
   int i = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ...
}
```

Which it's the best practice to do this?

Comment: It is important to know what are you doing inside that stored procedure. If it is just an insert/update of few records I would not use a stored procedure at all but a proper written parameterized query (surely not using AddWithValue)

Comment: The stored procedure doesn't contain any complex operation, just a simple update. I don't use SQL queries inside my application to keep the application layers separated, so your suggestion does't help on my case.

Comment: You could also pass in XML and update it as a batch, also.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first approach and send all the data as a table type variable even if you are performing a simple `UPDATE` operation.

Cause in that case, you can perform a `update-join` by performing a `JOIN` with the table type variable and can update multiple records at once. At least, you will save multiple calls to the DB.